# How to call a servlet from primefaces?

Tags: jsf, servlets, primefaces

How I could call a servlet from primefaces ?

I tried something like this:

```
<p:commandLink action="/JasperServlet?reportFileName=#{report.reportName}" 
                               value="#{node.reportName}" 
                               ajax="false" 
                               global="false" 
                               process="@this"
                               target="blank"/>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

It has to be a normal GET link, not a POST link and for sure not an Ajax request if it's a file download:

```
<h:outputLink value="/JasperServlet?reportFileName=#{report.reportName}" target="_blank">
    #{node.reportName}
</h:outputLink>
```

You can even use a plain HTML `<a>` element:

```
<a href="/JasperServlet?reportFileName=#{report.reportName}" target="_blank">
    #{node.reportName}
</a>
```

Either way, the servlet's `doGet()` will be called.

Comment: But how to use prime faces AJAX to update components value. Currently all listeners resolve to methods on CDI beans or JSF Backing Beans. How to get the result of ajax call and update the value of the p:inputText itself. Can this be done in primefaces aware javascript ?